# Paypal php passing handling fee parameter

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Now I'm addind parameter - `handling`, but in Paypal page gedding label *Shipping and handling* , this label is not correct form me bacause I sell inteligence items and there is no shipping.

What parameter is same as handling but have label *Handling*

I try all items from this official page, but no one is what I need.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't change the name of the parameter corresponding on the checkout page . Instead you use the cart upload button and pass the "handling" as line item so that it will be shown as another item on the checkout page . 
Kindly refer the below link :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/

You can click the below link to see how it will look like :

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart&upload=1&business=seller%40dezignerfotos.com&item_name_1=Item+Name+1&amount_1=1.00&item_name_2=Handling&amount_2=2.00&